# Why list.remove() doesn't work "properly"?

Tags: python

I have a class (Points) which has 4 lists and a list container. in my main I'm trying to pop a value from one of the lists. If the list becomes empty, then I remove it from the container. This all works fine, but sometimes the output says it tries to remove the same list from the container as before. Why is it working in this way?

My code:

```
class Points():

    def __init__(self):
        points = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five"]
        self.A = points.copy()
        self.B = points.copy()
        self.C = points.copy()
        self.D = points.copy()
        self.container = [self.A, self.B, self.C, self.D]

    def getPoint(self, letter, index):
        try:
            res = self.container[letter].pop(index-1)

            if (len(self.A) == 0) and (self.A in self.container):
                print("OUT OF A")
                self.container.remove(self.A)
            if (len(self.B) == 0) and (self.B in self.container):
                print("OUT OF B")
                self.container.remove(self.B)
            if (len(self.C) == 0) and (self.C in self.container):
                print("OUT OF C")
                self.container.remove(self.C)
            if (len(self.D) == 0) and (self.D in self.container):
                print("OUT OF D")
                self.container.remove(self.D)
        except:
            return -1
        return res

if __name__ == "__main__":
    m_Points = Points()

    for item in range(25):
        try:
            letterCode = randint(0,len(m_Points.container)-1)
            letter = m_Points.container[letterCode]
            index = randint(0, len(letter) )
            print("#{}. {}".format(item, m_Points.getPoint(letterCode, index) ))
        except:
            print("No more points")
            break
```

The output:

```
#0. Four
#1. One
#2. Three
#3. One
#4. Five
#5. Three
#6. Five
#7. Four
#8. Four
#9. Two
OUT OF B
#10. Two
#11. Two
OUT OF A           <--- First time A
#12. One
#13. Five
#14. Four
#15. Three
OUT OF A           <--- A AGAIN?
#16. One
#17. Five
#18. Two
OUT OF A           <--- and again...
#19. Three
No more points
```

Comment: "in" and "remove" work by equality, not identity. Therefore only some  empty list is removed not necessarily the desired one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is the way `in` and `remove` work.

Your confusion probably stems from a misconception that `in` asks if a particular container contains *a specific object*, and remove *removes a specific object*, and so when you call, say, `.remove(self.A)`, you want *the `list` pointed to by `self.A` to be removed.

However, what instead happens is that `in` just looks if an object with a particular value exists in the container, and `remove` removes the first object with that value in the container. In both cases, that need not be `self.A`, *just an object with the same value*.

Therefore, eventually, we will have something like this:

```
self.A = ['First']
self.container = [['First'], ['First'], ['First']]

# ...check and remove goes here
```

In this situation, what happens is that since `self.container` *does* contain a `list` with value equal to `self.A` *and* `self.A` is not empty, the first check passes and you reach `print('OUT OF A')`. Then, the first `list` is removed, *but the condition is still true the next iteration*, since all the remaining `lists` have the same value!